# Add css based on timer value

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to change the color of font based on my timer reaching <= 30 seconds. I am using [this countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) as my timer. So far, I am able to change the color, etc... but it adds it regardless of the time, etc. I'm fairly new to jQuery, so any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var seconds = $(".time-increment").val();

    $("#timer").countdown({
        until: +seconds, 
        format: 'MS', 
        layout: '{mn} {ml}, <span class="seconds-actual">{sn}</span> {sl} remaining',
        onExpiry: reload,
        onTick: checkFont
        }); 

    function reload() {
        var id = $("#item-content").attr('class');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../modal_content.adam.php',
            data: 'Qwicksale_id='+id,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#item-content").hide().html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**UPDATED**

I added a function for the onTick - The styled class is red all of the time, not just when seconds is less than or equal to 30?

```
function checkFont(seconds2) {
        if(seconds2[5] == 0 && seconds2[6] <= '30') {
            $('.hasCountdown').css('color', 'red');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Specifically where `class="seconds-actual"`.

Comment: you may simply use `until: seconds` no need of `+` there...

Comment: ".seconds-actual" is added by the countdown plugin. {sn} tag is the number that it is displaying - I seem to be able to get the value, but not able to test it correctly for my condition?

Comment: Solution: Using onTick callback, and testing for both the MINUTES and SECONDS column (since I only wanted the last 30 seconds of the countdown, not every last 30 seconds of every minute).

Comment: @Alpinestar22 What happens if you do `seconds2[6] <= 30` (30 as a number, not a string)?

Comment: @JasonP, I just changed it.. seems to work either as a string or number. I have it as a number now and is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `if(seconds2 <= 30) { ... }` block only executes once, when the page loads.

You need to use the `onTick` callback and check the remaining time in that handler.

See the second example on the "Callbacks" tab in the documentation: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: I believe this is the correct way to do it. It looks like it is an issue of reading the value of .seconds-actual... my condition seems to be what is not working?

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you can see that the remaining time is passed to the `onTick` handler. I would use that to check the time remaining instead of trying to read it from the DOM.

Comment: Great advice, I am now testing what the handler is passing back.. I still seem to have a hard time reading the value though. I seem to be getting the whole class red regardless of time left?

Answer (score 0):

Its add the color regardless of the time because you are just checking `if(seconds2 <= 30)` `on page load` then changing the color if this condition is true regardless of the time...

You may want to check this inside the `success` function like so:

```
function reload() {
    var id = $("#item-content").attr('class');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../modal_content.adam.php',
        data: 'Qwicksale_id='+id,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#item-content").hide().html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
            if(seconds2 <= 30) {
               $('.hasCountdown').css('color', 'red');
            }
        }
    });
}`
```

You may want to try

```
if(seconds2 <= 30) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.hasCountdown').css('color', 'red');
   }, seconds2);
}
```