# Div blocks change colour with time

Tags: html

How do I make div blocks of mine change colour whith a timer? I want to make a background filled with colourful es that will change colour as time proceeds. Please help!!! I would LOVE SOME RAW CODE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add css based on timer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064585/add-css-based-on-timer-value)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`CSS3 Animation`**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/4trrcrm7/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
body {
  animation: colorIt 20s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes colorIt {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  10% {
    background: blue;
  }
  20% {
    background: green;
  }
  30% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background: pink;
  }
  50% {
    background: lightblue;
  }
  60% {
    background: orange;
  }
  70% {
    background: magenta;
  }
  80% {
    background: black;
  }
  90% {
    background: purple;
  }
  100% {
    background: lightgreen;
  }
}
```